# How to attach a debugger to WAS?

Tags: java, debugging

I need to attach a debugger to a remote instance of WAS and know that debugging is enabled.  The problem is getting WID or whatever IDE I wanted connected to the server so I can step through the code.

I tried using Netbeans to connect and I get handshake failed, connection interrupted.  The debugger is listening on port 7777.  If I go into the WID admin console, I need a username and password.  Would I need the same to attach a debugger, if so, where can I specify that?

Walter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I simply need to enable the service at startup then I should be able to connect?  I have to get permission first to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not add the following line to the startup script's parameters of WAS:

```
-Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=7777
```

And then attach your Netbeans remote debugger on port 7777

Comment: Actually, that is what is configured:

Enable service at server startup is set to false, but I still see something listening on that port.

Comment: Where is the WAS instance?....is it on your machine and you are seeing the port open?....What happens when you start your Netbeans debugger on port 7777, does it connect okay?

You may want to change suspend=n to suspend=y in the above line I gave you previously, because then WAS /should/ wait for a debugger to become attached before commencing its startup

Answer (score 0):

WAS can be configured for remote debugging [via the web administration console](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/info/aes/ae/utrb_debugsvc.html).

*It is also possible to configure this without starting WAS - via one of the profile XML files. But I don't remember the details and don't have WAS handy to check.*